# assign the final variable with the function return type

Tags: java, variables, final

In java i tried to assign the final variable with the function return value. But i got the compilation errors. Can anyone help me what is causing the errors here?

the code is like this:

```
public class A{
  private static final set<String> set1 = getSet();
  private Static Set<String> getSet(){
     Vector<String> vector1 = getVector();//some function which return the Vector of type String
     if(vector1!=null){
           set1=new HashSet<String>(vactor1);
     }
     else{
           set1= new HashSet<String>();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: can any one comment on this?

Comment: I get a lot of compilation errors too. Stuff like `set`, `Static`, `vactor1`.

Comment: Your third line, `private Static Set[...]`, will give compilation errors because `static` needs to be lowercase... The provided answer solves the issue with `final`.

Comment: And you don't even return a `Set` in that method.

Comment: Leave the syntax errors. My problem is assigning the final variable with the function causing compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final set<String> set1 = getSet();
```

`set1` is `final`, meaning that it **cannot** be changed.

However,

```
set1=new HashSet<String>(vactor1);
```

and

```
set1= new HashSet<String>();
```

are trying to change it. See [**JLS 4.12.4. final Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable can be declared `final`. A `final` variable **may only be
>   assigned to once**. Declaring a variable `final` can serve as useful
>   documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid
>   programming errors.
>
> It is a **compile-time error** if a `final` variable is assigned to unless
>   it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.

I don't know if it's a typo or not, but `static` should be all lower-case, not `Static`.

Comment: In the above only either either if or else block does execute. So i am not changing final variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
private static final Set<String> set1 = getSet();
```

means this: It calls a method `getSet`, which it expects to return a value, and then it assigns the returned value into `set1`.  (Note that it needs to be `Set`, not `set`.)

For this to work, `getSet` actually has to return a value, using the `return` statement.  So instead of

```
set1=new HashSet<String>(vactor1);
```

the statement should be

```
return new HashSet<String>(vector1);  // make sure vector1 is spelled correctly
```

and similarly with the other `set1=` statement in `getSet`.